# Replacing more than one line breaks by only one line break

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace any number of `\r\n` by only one `\r\n\r\n` in C#. Sorry if it a stupid question but I am new to regex.
Actually I tried

```
clearstring = Regex.Replace(clearstring, @"\r\n+", "\r\n\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but it did not work, any suggestions? I will be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
clearstring = Regex.Replace(clearstring, @"(\r\n)+", "\r\n\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The rule is that quantifiers (the plus sign in your case) only apply on the immediately preceding group or character class, which in your case is only \n. If you want to include multiple characters or classes, you should group them in paranthesis.

Comment: Good to see I was able to help. Always use the green checkbox to the left if an answer works for you.

Comment: That's comment is not about corrent issue. But if i supply `/r/r/n/r/n/n/r/n` , your code will give me two new line in output. So, when it is a security concern, i would use a `while` loop to clear the string untill there is no two new line one after. But it's not must implemented in this case

Comment: @doNet but +1 for your 1st comment. I also dislike people who really get help but dont check the green box. Lol

Comment: Please @silentboy can you explain how to use `while` loop by the code

Comment: I do not know it in your language. But can you convert my psudocode to your  programming language:  `while(mystring match /r/n/r/n) mystring = clear(mystring);`

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(\r\n){2,}", Environment.NewLine)
```

This will replace only if two or more consecutive empty lines are found